# Using ngModel to bind dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I'm fairly new to Angular so bear with me if I have some rookie mistakes here :)
I am dynamically adding inputs based on some properties that need to be filled out (this.properties) and I want to bind each of those dynamic inputs to some object (this.selectedProperties = {}) so that I end up with something like this.

```
this.properties = [new MyData { name = "theName", examples = "theExamples" },
                   new MyData { name = "anotherName", examples = "moreExamples" }];
this.selectedProperties = { "theName": "valueFromBinding", "anotherName": "anotherValueFromBinding" }
```

Here's a slimmed down version of what I have so far. Everything is working other than the ngModel to set the selected values.

```
<div *ngFor="let property of this.properties">
    <label>{{property.name}}</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{property.examples}}"
       [ngModel]="this.selectedProperties[property.name]" 
       name="{{property.name}}Input">
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ngModel` 's syntax is `[(ngModel)]` which is called "banana in a box"  :D

Comment: remove the `this.` it should be just `[ngModel]="selectedProperties[property.name]"` the same goes for the `*ngFor` remove `this.`

Comment: removing "this" didn't help, but adding the parenthesis did! I thought that was only for 2-way binding and that I would only need one-way, but that did the trick! Thanks! If you post that as the answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: of course you should remove the `this` too, but about the binding, if you just make it one-way, the input only gets the value of `selectedProperties[property.name]` and doesn't change the `selectedProperties[property.name]` 's value when user changes it...

Comment: @GHB *"...of course you should remove the `this` too..."*. Although it's not recommended to use `this` keyword in template, he can use it and it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let property of properties">
    <label>{{property.name}}</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{property.examples}}" [ngModel]="selectedProperties[property.name]" name="{{property.name}}Input">
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    properties = [
        new MyData { name: "theName", examples: "theExamples" },
        new MyData { name: "anotherName", examples: "moreExamples" }
    ];

    selectedProperties = {
        "theName": "valueFromBinding",
        "anotherName": "anotherValueFromBinding"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed two way binding so that selectedProperties[property.name] would update when the user changed it in the UI